# How to get all elements in arrays type Map and send to JSP file by JSTL in Spring

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I have a JSON attribute's value in Java, I can get the value properly but I couldn't send to JSP file..

**My JSON:**

```
 periods =  
 {"number":1,"name":"Tonight","startTime":"2023-06-05T22:00:00-04:00","endTime":"2023-06-06T06:00:00-04:00","isDaytime":false,"temperature":63,"temperatureUnit":"F","temperatureTrend":"rising","probabilityOfPrecipitation":{"unitCode":"wmoUnit:percent","value":null},"dewpoint":{"unitCode":"wmoUnit:degC","value":8.333333333333334},"relativeHumidity":{"unitCode":"wmoUnit:percent","value":50},"windSpeed":"9 mph","windDirection":"NW","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/night/sct?size=medium","shortForecast":"Partly Cloudy","detailedForecast":"Partly cloudy. Low around 63, with temperatures rising to around 65 overnight. Northwest wind around 9 mph."}
 {"number":2,"name":"Tuesday","startTime":"2023-06-06T06:00:00-04:00","endTime":"2023-06-06T18:00:00-04:00","isDaytime":true,"temperature":76,"temperatureUnit":"F","temperatureTrend":null,"probabilityOfPrecipitation":{"unitCode":"wmoUnit:percent","value":40},"dewpoint":{"unitCode":"wmoUnit:degC","value":10},"relativeHumidity":{"unitCode":"wmoUnit:percent","value":52},"windSpeed":"7 to 15 mph","windDirection":"NW","icon":"https://api.weather.gov/icons/land/day/tsra_hi,40?size=medium","shortForecast":"Haze","detailedForecast":"Haze and a chance of rain showers and patchy smoke between 8am and 11am, then haze and patchy smoke and a chance of showers and thunderstorms. Mostly sunny, with a high near 76. Northwest wind 7 to 15 mph. Chance of precipitation is 40%."}
```

**This is controller:**

```
    @RequestMapping("/show")
    public ModelAndView showForecast(ModelMap model) throws IOException {
    
    ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
    mv.setViewName("show");             
    
    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity = restTemplate.getForEntity("https://api.golde.gov", String.class);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
           
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);
            
    JsonNode properties = objectMapper.readTree(responseEntity.getBody()).get("properties");
    JsonNode periods = properties.get("periods");
    // Forecast[] forecasts = objectMapper.readValue(periods.toString(), Forecast[].class);     
    
    if (periods.isArray()) {
        for (final JsonNode objNode : periods) {
            System.out.println(objNode);                                
            result = objectMapper.convertValue(objNode, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});                
        }
        
        // mv.addObject("result", result);
        
        model.addAttribute("result", result);
    }       
    return mv;
   }
```

I want to send all values to jsp and i used:

```
model.addAttribute("results", result);
```

**This is JSP file:**

```
<c:forEach items="${results}" var="result">   
        <td>${result.number}</td> </br>
        <td>${result.name}</td> </br>
        <td>${result.startTime}</td> </br>          
        <td>${result.endTime}</td> </br>                
        <td>${result.isDaytime}</td> </br>
        <td>${result.temperature}</td> </br>            
        <td>${result.temperatureUnit}</td> </br>            
        <td>${result.temperatureTrend}</td> </br>           
        <td>${result.windSpeed}</td> </br>
        <td>${result.windDirection}</td> </br>                          
        <img src="${result.icon}" alt="Image" height="50px" width="50px">           
        <td>${result.shortForecast}</td> </br>
        <td>${result.detailedForecast}</td> </br>           
</c:forEach>
```

However when i run i only received 1 row is:

```
 {"number":3,"name":"Monday","startTime":"2023-06-12T06:00:00-04:00","endTime":"2023-06-12T18:00:00-04:00","isDaytime":true,"temperature":77,"temperatureUnit":"F","temperatureTrend":null,"probabilityOfPrecipitation":{"unitCode":"wmoUnit:percent"}
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]
How I can get all JSON data

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in your code, this block

```java
for (final JsonNode objNode : periods) {
            System.out.println(objNode);                                
            result = objectMapper.convertValue(objNode, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){});                
}
```

you set the result variable value to the latest element of periods array. That's why you only received one record in result map. To fix that, you can change the result variable to List<Map<String, Object>>. For example

```
List<Map<String, Object>> result = new ArrayList<>();
```

and in the for loop

```java
for (final JsonNode objNode : periods) {
            System.out.println(objNode);                                
            result.add(objectMapper.convertValue(objNode, new TypeReference<Map<String, Object>>(){}));                
}
```

Comment: Hi @Phat Nguyen: i have try your suggest, but it happen an error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "number"
Could you check again ?

Comment: Hi @KhanhLuongVan, I can run successfully with the backend code, the error must come from JSP. Can you provide github link to your source code?

Comment: Thank @Phat Nguyen: i only run on my local, and not use git for this, can you send to me your code you run success ? send to my email: khanh.luongvan.app@gmail.com

Comment: Or could you updated your code in answer ? include jsp file